# How to add a diacritic to an English letter

Tags: ruby, unicode

I have a string, for example:

```
"Xin chao moi nguoi"
```

And I would like to programmatically convert that string to:

```
"Xin chào mọi người"
```

I just need a rough idea how to start to research. Any suggestion?

This is not translation. Both strings below are from one language, but the first one misses the diacritic. This program will add the diacritic to an English letter.

`a` -> `ă`

Comment: If the same letter is sometimes supposed to appear with a certain diacritic and sometimes without (or with a different diacritic), then there is no deterministic way to do that as the information is gone. Is there a deterministic rule for when to add which diacritic? Without it, your question is not answerable.

Comment: @sawa it was before the question title was edited. Removing

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev I am not sure about the title before, but I suppose it meant Latin letters, not Latin language. If that is the case, then it is more appropriate to write Latin than write English. Or, maybe Roman letters are more popular words.

Comment: @sawa It's true, there wouldn't be a way to look at an individual letter on its own, but you could use a dictionary of words (see my answer).

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure there's a specific library to address your situation, but I'm not familiar with everything in Ruby. You could try something like the following, however:

Create a list of the specially-encoded words, and a mapping of basic characters to the complex ones.

Then, when you have your basic encoding of a candidate word, filter your list for words that match, character-by-character, keeping those that either match the current character exactly, or that have an acceptable substitute in the mapping that was previously defined.

A quick and dirty example:

```
wordList = ['chào', 'chao', 'chaobella'] #etc...
charMap = {'a'=>['a', 'à'], 'c'=>['c'], 'h'=>['h'], 'o'=>['o', 'ọ', 'ờ']} # etc...

word = 'chao'
filterList = wordList

# for each character in the word
word.split("").each_with_index do |char, index|
  # get the list of characters you'd like it to match
  matchingChars = charMap[char]
  # select the words that match at this index
  filterList = filterList.select{ |w| matchingChars.include? w.split("")[index] }
end

# filter out longer words
filterList = filterList.select{ |w| word.length == w.length }

puts "Words that match: " + filterList.join(",")
```

You'll still need to factor it out into a function, and determine what to do if there is more than one word that matches.

Comment: Actually you could address me any kind of language. I just need a rough idea

Comment: Was the above the kind of thing you were looking for?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Unicode combining characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character) and compose the resulting characters from their base character:

```
   a   +   ̀      = à
U+0061 + U+0300
```

You can get the combining characters with [Unicode decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence), i.e. the *Normalization Form Canonical Decomposition* (NFD). The inverse, composing multiple characters to one single character, is the *Normalization Form Canonical Composition* (NFC).

You could use [this Ruby Unicode library](http://www.yoshidam.net/Ruby.html#unicode) for composition and decomposition.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how much you want to do. If you just encode your strings in UTF-8 (start your file with `#encoding: utf-8`), you can make a rudimentary changing dictionary:

```
conversions = {
  "a" => "á",
  "e" => "é"
}
#And so on... (or with words, as @Hannele said)
str.gsub(/[aeiou]/, conversions)
```

Feel free to replace any of the conversions to how you see fit. Remember, though, this will replace all vowels in the string. It won't do what makes sense for the human language.

Answer (score 1):

For a one to one char conversion there is the [tr](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-tr) method:

```
#encoding: utf-8
p "Xin chao moi nguoi".tr('aou', 'àọư')
#=>"Xin chàọ mọi ngưọi"
```

Comment: +1 but this is completely wrong but the OP won't get what he wants in a SO answer

Answer (score -1):

You are translating the English to Vietnamese.

A Ruby [gem](http://rubygems.org/gems/language-translator) to translate a string from one language to another using google api.